# Search with content types

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

Is it possible to search for multiple content types (products, categories, blogs, articles etc) in Magento? I got the search result for products only. I want to display products when to search for the category name.

Answer (score 1):

No. The default Magento search is for catalog products only.

If you need extended search functionality, you should have a look at other Magento extensions and search engines.

Comment: Thanx @Anna for your information

Answer (score 1):

Usually Magento doesn’t have this possibility but there are all conditions for that. There are a lot of modules. They can do it. 
Here is a small list:

1. [Magento Search Suite extension v1.2.0](http://www.mageworx.com/search-suite-magento-extension.html)
2. [Advanced Search 1.4.8](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-search.html)
3. [Sphinx Search Ultimate](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html)

If you decide to write own similar module, you must know that it is very long process (few weeks).
I used one of these modules.

P.S.: If you decide to install one of third-party modules, you should consult the developers how many fit the selected modules to your requirements. Do not spend time and money on something that will not work for you.

Comment: Thanx @Eugene for your information